# PowerShell - why doesn't certain request types work?

Tags: powershell, ssl, web, port

This is really odd to me..  The ones for http and https appear fine..  The ones for port 8080 and 8443 do not..

```
$ip="1.2.3.4"
$urls = "http://$ip","http://"$ip":8080","https://$ip","https://"$ip":8443"
foreach ($u in $urls)
{ 
"$u"
}
```

The results show:

```
PS C:\Documents and Settings\user> D:\WORK\ps\test.ps1
Unexpected token 'ip' in expression or statement.
At D:\WORK\ps\test.ps1:2 char:37
+ $rsaurls = "http://$ip","http://"$ip <<<< ":8080","https://$ip","https://"$ip":8443"
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (ip:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

If we remove the quoting..

```
$ip="1.2.3.4"
$urls = "http://$ip","http://$ip:8080","https://$ip","https://$ip:8443"
foreach ($u in $urls)
{ 
"$u"
}

And the results show:
PS C:\Documents and Settings\user> D:\WORK\ps\test.ps1
http://1.2.3.4
http://
https://1.2.3.4
https://
```

I think I need to escape the ":"..

I am closer..

```
$ip="1.2.3.4"
$urls = "http://$ip","http://$ip^:8080","https://$ip","https://$ip^:8443"
foreach ($u in $urls)
{ 
"$u"
}
```

and the results:

```
PS C:\Documents and Settings\user> D:\WORK\ps\test.ps1
http://1.2.3.4
http://1.2.3.4^:8080
https://1.2.3.4
https://1.2.3.4^:8443
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe PowerShell is interpreting `$ip:8080` as a variable whose scope is "ip" and name is "8080". Use braces to clarify the variable name:

```
"https://${ip}:8080"
```

Answer (score 0):

OK..  Escape with ` character did it!

```
$ip="1.2.3.4"
$urls = "http://$ip","http://$ip`:8080","https://$ip","https://$ip`:8443"
foreach ($u in $urls)
{ 
"$u"
}
```

and the results:

```
PS C:\Documents and Settings\user> D:\WORK\ps\test.ps1
http://1.2.3.4
http://1.2.3.4:8080
https://1.2.3.4
https://1.2.3.4:8443
```